# Windows form does not work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have recently created an application for x64 system. The problem which is continuously occurring is that, the application works on my PC but does not works on my laptop. As soon as I try to launch the application it displays MSVCR120D.dll is missing but I have all the packages from 2010-2013 installed on my laptop. Even if I copy-paste the dll file externally it gives me an error something like 0xc000007b.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your *app* is compiled in **debug mode** and also it is using the ***.dll* *CRT* version** (check [[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546) for more details), that's why it requires *MSVCR120**D**.dll* (notice the **D** as its name's last letter).
You must rebuild your *app* in **release mode** since *CRT* debug libraries cannot be redistributed. In that case the app will require *MSVCR120.dll* (no **D**) which is allowed to be distributed (and it could even be there installed by other *app*).

Don't manually copy these *.dll*s other machines, but use the installers: [[MS]: Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

I am assuming that your app doesn't have any *.NET Framework* dependencies.

If you want to check the dependencies of an *.exe* / *.dll* file, try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) (or newer [[GitHub]: lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)).

Now, if none of the above succeeds, I am posting a workaround (gainarie) that is to be as much as possible avoided especially if your app uses *.dll*s created by you:

In *VStudio* *IDE*, go to your *app*'s project options (properties) *Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library* and choose either one of the options **except *Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)*** (as that one won't work), depending on your project configuration (debug or release), and rebuild your *app*.
Now the *app* either:

- Won't be needing the *CRT* *.dll*.
  *CRT* code won't be in the *.dll*, but rather inserted directly in your *app*'s *.exe* - as a result the new *.exe* will have a bigger size).
  This applies to */MT*, */MTd*
- Will be needing the distributable *CRT* (*.dll*) which can be installed on *Win* machines.
  This applies to */MD*

As a general practice, when creating software supposed to run on multiple machines, **build it in release mode**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I compile it a blank windows pops up on my screen I don't know why....

Comment: That's not good. Could you post Visual Studio's "Output" window's content here?

Comment: I can link you to the screenshot of my form though. http://i.imgur.com/yGlVxlf.png