# Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers

Encountered on Visual Studio **2013**, but it's reproducible with any version.

I cloned the protocol buffer library from github, ran CMake-gui on it (I left everything to default, so it's the static version), only built libprotobuf (other project failed for some reason, cmd.exe error, might have something to do with tests, but libprotobuf builds fine).

My project uses headers generated with the .proto file found on the mapbox vector tiles spec's github.

When I link, I first have this error

`Error  1   error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'   s:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility`

I tried disabling it with `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in additional command line arguments, but then I have other errors:

`Error  1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj   S:\eiogit3\misc-projs\mapload\mapload\libprotobufd.lib(common.obj)`

Comment: So, you built `libprotobuf` static version (_.lib_) using CMake, and now you are trying to link it in your VStudio app?

Comment: Yes, I built it with MSVC 2013, and am now linking it to my project, also using MSVC 2013

Comment: [here](https://github.com/jokoon/eio/tree/master/misc-projs/mapload) is the project file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a mismatch of how the *VStudio C (and C++) RunTime Library* (***VCRTLib*** or ***UCRT*** - check [[SO]: How to circumvent Windows Universal CRT headers dependency on vcruntime.h (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838055/4788546)) is used by your project and by *LibProtoBuf* project. Let me detail:

Let's say there's some *C* (*C++*) code. The purpose of that code is to be run. Than can be achieved:

- Directly: including that code in an *VC Application* type project - which will generate an *.exe*
- Indirectly: including the code in an *VC Library* type project - which will generate a *library* which will only be able to run when called from another *.exe* (that calls that library). The library can be:

  - **static**: all the *C* (*C++*) code will be compiled and stored in a *.lib* file. You will need that file when using the library in another project (whether it's an application or a library) - at **link** time. Note that all the needed code from your *.lib* will be "copied" into the other project
  - **dynamic**: you will have 2 files now: a *.dll* file which will contain the compiled (and linked) code, and a *.lib* file<sup>***(1)***</sup> which will contain "pointers" (if you will) to the code in the *.dll* file. When using the library in another project, you will also need the *.lib* file at **link** time, but now it won't contain the code so it won't be copied in the other library (the other library will be smaller), but at **run** time the other library will need the *.dll* file

You can check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) for details of how *C* (*C++*) code gets to be transformed in executable format. Also *Google* is full of articles about differences between static and dynamic libraries, when to use one or the other, an example can be found on [[SO]: When to use dynamic vs. static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140061/4788546).

As you guessed, the ***CRT*** or *C RunTime library* (that contains the underlying system that makes *C* code able to run - one example are memory management functions: *malloc*, *free*) makes no exception - it's the equivalent of *Nix*'s *libc.a* (static or archive) vs. *libc.so* (dynamic or shared object) - but in *VStudio* it's a little bit more complicated:

- Static *CRT* resides in *libcmt.lib*
- Dynamic *CRT* resides in *msvcrt.lib* which "points" to *msvcr###.dll*<sup>***(2)***</sup> (*msvcr120.dll* for *VStudio 2013*)

**Notes**:

- A "**d**" at the end of the library name (*msvcr**d**.lib*), means that it's built with debug symbols (also bigger and slower)
- ***C++*** runtime library is under the exact situation; the names have an extra **p**: *libc**p**mt.lib*, *msvc**p**rt.lib*, *msvc**p**120.dll*
- For more details, check [[MS.Docs]: CRT Library Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features)

Now, *UCRT* parts, are not included in the project like any other lib (*Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies*), but because their nature (static or dynamic) is required at compile time they are configured from: [[MS.Docs]: /MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library), where there are 4 available choices:

1. *Multi-threaded (**/MT**)*
2. *Multi-threaded Debug (**/MTd**)*
3. *Multi-threaded DLL (**/MD**)*
4. *Multi-threaded Debug DLL (**/MDd**)*

Obviously, the ones that contain "Debug" are when building for *Debug* configuration while the other ones for *Release*; the key point is that the ones that have **DLL** are using the **dynamic** runtime version, while the other ones the **static** version.

**Back to your error**: the linker complains that *main.obj* (part of your project) has ***MDd_DynamicDebug*** (linking against the *dynamic debug* version), while *common.obj* (part of *LibProtoBuf* project) has ***MTd_StaticDebug*** (linking against the *static debug* version), so you link against 2 runtimes in the same executable (or *.dll*) - which is not possible.

In order to fix it, you should make sure that both *LibProtoBuf* and your main project have the same value for *UCRT*.
Of course it's simpler to change your main project setting to match *LibProtoBuf*'s one, but it's recommended to use the dynamic runtime version (things can get messy in larger projects that have *.dll*s involved) even if this requires to recompile *LibProtoBuf* (well, if changing that option generates errors that make *LibProtoBuf* very hard to build, and your project is going to stay this simple, you can use the static *UCRT*).

**Note**: Not to mistake *UCRT* type (static / dynamic) with the way *LibProtoBuf* is being built (static at this point, but I'm sure that it can be built as dynamic too).

---

#### Update *#0*

Adding some additional info on the above note, as some comments requested it, and it might be useful to other users.

There are 2 aspects about a library (including *LibProtoBuf*), that are **totally unrelated**:

1. **Library type** (the way it is being built): *dynamic* / *static*
2. ***UCRT* type** (the way it uses *UCRT*): again, *dynamic* / *static*

So, there are **4** perfectly valid combinations:

1. Dynamic library using dynamic *UCRT*
2. Dynamic library using static *UCRT*
3. Static library using dynamic *UCRT*
4. Static library using static *UCRT*

For *LibProtoBuf*, each of the aspects is controlled by a boolean *CMake* option:

1. Library type: ***protobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS***
2. *UCRT* type: ***protobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME***

The 2 flags can be set by either:

- *CMake-GUI*
- *CMake CmdLine* (passing them as arguments - e.g.: `-Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF`)

The above 4 combinations are thus *possible* (at least in *v**3.5***), but ***#2.*** **is disabled by default** (specifying `-Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON` will build a *.dll* which will link to the **dynamic** *UCRT*), in order to avoid possible runtime problems, and enabling it requires manual intervention.

For more details regarding build instructions (via *cmake*), check: [[GitHub]: protocolbuffers/protobuf - (master) protobuf/cmake/README.md](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md).

---

#### Footnotes

- ***#1***: The *.lib* file will only be created if the library **exports symbols**, as it wouldn't make sense otherwise (nothing needed at link time, and the *.dll* will be created, but pretty much unusable)
- ***#2***: For newer *VStudio* versions (starting with ***v2015***), the ***msvcr(t)*** part has been replaced by ***vcruntime*** (or at least this is the entrypoint, as it was split in smaller logical pieces (check the *URL* at the beginning))

Comment: Does this, by any chance, solve the problem https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/cmake ?

Comment: Thank you, it now builds (with the -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in command line). I already knew the difference between static and dynamic, but I had no idea about that runtime library setting. And actually, the google protobuf doc states that it's advised to use the static version, not the dynamic version: https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/cmake#dlls-vs-static-linking

Comment: Glad to hear it works. I just read the comments on the link you provided. Now regarding your previous question, if it's about the template export at the end, then I don't think it does.

Comment: Question: Can I build a static library that uses dynamic runtime and the other way around?

Comment: Yes. By default the way *libprotobuf* is built dictates the way *VCRTLib* is used. Build types are controlled by 2 flags. Here's how i built the static *libprotobuf* version using dynamic *VCRTLib* `-Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF -Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`. I should add this piece of info into the answer.