# Run-Time 53 Error while loading C++ DLL in excel vba

Tags: c++, vba, runtime-error, dllimport

I compiled with VS2017 on my PC (windows 10) a c++ DLL, that contains some routines. I loaded this file on Excel 2013 with the command

```
Private Declare Function Myfunc Lib "[PATH]\FILE.dll" (ByVal x As Double) As 
Double
```

I do not use "alias" because I created a .DEF file in project folder. **With these settings and on my PC, the loading works and I can use the DLL.**
I also tried to move the .dll file in some different directories on my PC, and in any case it works fine.

**HOWEVER:**

**Problem 1:**

it arises when I copy this DLL to another PC, which is an old **Windows XP** with Service Pack 3. Of course I already paid attention to compile in VS2017 C++ with "Platform v141_xp", SDK version 7.0 and predefined version of /clr.

The old PC contains Windows XP SP3, SDk 7.1, .NET Framework 4, C++ redistributable 2010, Office 2007 (update SP3).

When I try to import this DLL in XP with Office 2007, it returns the error

*Error Run Time 53
It is not possible to find the file "[PATH]\File.dll"*

**Problem 2:**

I try to make the same operation with another PC again. This time this PC is recent with Windows 10, Office 2013, C++ Red 2010, but **not** SDK.

The problem remains.

*Error Run Time '53' etc...*

What am I missing? I would like to use this DLL in any PC... is it possible?

Comment: You need to install the VS 2017 redistributable, or use static linking to the runtime.

Comment: What do you mean with "linking to the run time"?

Comment: *Static sorry for the dummy question

Comment: Er, your DLL needs a runtime. Try some research on that topic.

Comment: Check my answer on [\[SO\]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MSVC 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116437/errors-when-linking-to-protobuf-3-on-msvc-2013) (the paragraph related to _Code Generation -> Runtime Library_).