# Paradoxon: silent crash on Python's ctypes.CDLL when importing, but not when running directly - how is this possible?

Tags: python, python-import, ctypes

So, being a Linux guy I stumbled into something pretty puzzling on Windows that I just can't explain.

I have a project structure analougus to this example:

```
D:\PROJECT
|
|   tolkien.py
|   __init__.py
|   
\---MiddleEarth
    |   gondor.py
    |   isengrad.c
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    \---lib
            isengrad.so
```

**Problem:** I compile `isengrad.c` into the shared libary `isengrad.so`, then load it in `gondor.py`. My aim is to import `gondor.py` into `tolkien.py`.
While `gondor.py` runs flawlessly when it is run directly, when I import it, the code exits at the point when I load the shared library via `ctypes.CDLL`, without any error messages.

**Reproduction:**
The content of the files (added some "status messages" to follow where the problem happens):

*isengrad.c:*

```
int isengrad(int hobbit){
    return hobbit/2;
}
```

This is then compiled to *isengrad.so* with

```
D:\project>chdir MiddleEarth
D:\project\MiddleEarth>gcc -fPIC -shared -o lib/isengrad.so isengrad.c
```

The shared library is then accessed in *gondor.py*:

```
print("started gondor")

import os, ctypes
path_to_isengrad = "D:/project/MiddleEarth/lib/isengrad.so"  

print("gondor loads isengrad")
gondor = ctypes.CDLL(path_to_isengrad)     # <--- crashes here when imported, not when ran directly
print("gondor loaded isengrad")


gondor.isengrad.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)

def faramir(hobbit):
    catched_hobbits = gondor.isengrad(hobbit)
    return catched_hobbits

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(faramir(5))
    print("gondor ran")

print("gondor finished")
```

which is then imported in *tolkien.py*:

```
print("started tolkien")
from MiddleEarth import gondor
print("tolkien imported gondor")

got = gondor.faramir(4)
print(got)

print("tolkien worked")
```

Now check what happens when I use `gondor.py` directly VS when I import it in `tolkien.py`:

```
D:\project>python MiddleEarth/gondor.py
started gondor
gondor loads isengrad
gondor loaded isengrad
2
gondor ran
gondor finished

D:\project>python tolkien.py
started tolkien
started gondor
gondor loads isengrad

D:\project>
```

Directly running it causes no problem at all. But importing it causes the whole thing to crash without any word and traceback when loading the shared library. How is this even happening? I even hard-coded the path to the shared library, so different working directory shouldn't be a problem... I didn't have any problem with the very same project on Kubuntu, so this is probably some Windows-related stuff.

**Environment:**

- Python: `Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`
- OS: `Windows 10  10.0.17134 Build 17134` (installed on C:)
- GCC: Installed via Cygwin, version 7.4.0
- Please ask if any other details needed.

Comment: Any crash details? Any reason for using *gcc* (which version, part of which toolchain) and not *VStudio*?

Comment: @CristiFati I don't know any more details on the chrash, is there any way to get info about it (like a Python log or something)? I use gcc via Cygwin, gcc version is 7.4.0. I chose this over VStudio because of my (and the project's) Linux past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the moment I saw this question, I wanted to say it's *Undefined Behavior* (***UB***). *Python* comes with its *C* runtime (*UCRTLib*), while the *Cygwin* *.dll* comes with its own. Mixing compilers and *C* runtimes in a process, is generally a recipe for disaster. 
I found an official statement [[Cygwin]: 6.15. Can I link with both MSVCRT*.DLL and cygwin1.dll?](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.msvcrt-and-cygwin) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **No, you must use one or the other, they are mutually exclusive**.

Check [[SO]: How to circumvent Windows Universal CRT headers dependency on vcruntime.h (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838055/4788546) for more details on *MSVCRT*.DLL* (*VCRuntime*.dll*).

Now, the beauty of *UB* is that it describes a seemingly random behavior.

I've prepared a comprehensive example (slightly modifying your code).

- *isengrad.c*:

  ```c
  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define ISENGRAD_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define ISENGRAD_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  ISENGRAD_EXPORT_API int isengrad(int hobbit)
  {
      return hobbit / 2;
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import sys


  DLL_NAME = "./lib/isengrad_{:s}_{:03d}.{:s}".format(
      sys.argv[1][:3] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.platform[:3].lower(),
      cts.sizeof(cts.c_void_p) * 8,
      "dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so",
  )
  print("Attempting to load: {0:s}".format(DLL_NAME))
  dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
  print("DLL Loaded")


  def main(*argv):
      isengrad = dll.isengrad
      isengrad.argtypes = (cts.c_int,)
      isengrad.restype = cts.c_int

      res = isengrad(46)
      print("{:s} returned {:d}".format(isengrad.__name__, res))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(
          "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
              " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
              64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
              sys.platform,
          )
      )
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```
- *code01.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import sys

  import code00


  def main(*argv):
      pass


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(
          "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
              " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
              64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
              sys.platform,
          )
      )
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Outputs**:

- I'll be using 3 windows:

  - *Cmd* - *Win* (*032bit* and *064bit*)
  - *Cygwin*'s *Mintty*:

    - *064bit*
    - *032bit*
- Note that even if I'll paste each's contents in one chunk (to avoid scattering them), I switched between them when running the commands
- *Cygwin* *032bit*:

  > ```
  > [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q056855348]> ~/sopr.sh
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [032bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll isengrad.c
  > [032bit prompt]> ls lib/*.dll
  > lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll  lib/isengrad_win_032.dll  lib/isengrad_win_064.dll
  > [032bit prompt]>
  > [032bit prompt]> python ./code00.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] 32bit on cygwin
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [032bit prompt]>
  > [032bit prompt]> python ./code01.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] 32bit on cygwin
  >
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [032bit prompt]>
  > [032bit prompt]> python ./code00.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] 32bit on cygwin
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [032bit prompt]>
  > [032bit prompt]> python3 ./code01.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 17:45:56) [GCC 6.4.0] 32bit on cygwin
  >
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Cygwin* *064bit*:

  > ```
  > [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q056855348]> ~/sopr.sh
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [064bit prompt]>  gcc -fPIC -shared -o lib/isengrad_cyg_064.dll isengrad.c
  > [064bit prompt]> ls lib/*.dll
  > lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll  lib/isengrad_cyg_064.dll  lib/isengrad_win_032.dll  lib/isengrad_win_064.dll
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48) [GCC 7.4.0] 64bit on cygwin
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> python ./code01.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48) [GCC 7.4.0] 64bit on cygwin
  >
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48) [GCC 7.4.0] 64bit on cygwin
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> python ./code01.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48) [GCC 7.4.0] 64bit on cygwin
  >
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Cmd*:

  > ```
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056855348]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b lib
  >
  > [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
  > **********************************************************************
  > ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.14
  > ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
  > **********************************************************************
  > [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
  >
  > [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL isengrad.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:lib\isengrad_win_064.dll
  > isengrad.c
  >    Creating library lib\isengrad_win_064.lib and object lib\isengrad_win_064.exp
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
  > **********************************************************************
  > ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.14
  > ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
  > **********************************************************************
  > [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'
  >
  > [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL isengrad.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:lib\isengrad_win_032.dll
  > isengrad.c
  >    Creating library lib\isengrad_win_032.lib and object lib\isengrad_win_032.exp
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b lib\*.dll
  > isengrad_cyg_032.dll
  > isengrad_cyg_064.dll
  > isengrad_win_032.dll
  > isengrad_win_064.dll
  >
  > [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
  >
  > [prompt]> :: ----- Python 032bit -----
  > [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;e:\Install\x86\Cygwin\Cygwin\Version\bin
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_032_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] 32bit on win32
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_032_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code01.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] 32bit on win32
  >
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_032_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] 32bit on win32
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_032_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code01.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_032.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] 32bit on win32
  >
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> :: ----- Python 064bit -----
  > [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\x64\Cygwin\Cygwin\AllVers\bin
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code01.py win
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_win_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
  >
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_064.dll
  > DLL Loaded
  > Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
  >
  > isengrad returned 23
  >
  > Done.
  >
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code01.py cyg
  > Attempting to load: ./lib/isengrad_cyg_064.dll
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
  > -1073741819
  > ```

As seen, cross compiler *.exe* - *.dll* worked in 7 (out of 8) cases (crashed on *064bit* *Win* *Python* with *code01.py*), while the same compiler worked in all 8 of them.

So, I'd advise that when playing with such environments, try to keep the compilers used to build various parts **consistent** (or **compatible** at least).

---

#### Update *#0*

I just thought of a reason why things could go wrong on *064bit*: `sizeof(long)` generally differs (sizes below are in bytes):

- ***4*** on *Win*
- ***8*** on *Cygwin* (on *Nix*, in general)

Same thing for `sizeof(long double)` (which is `2 * sizeof(long)`).
Check:

- [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546)
- [[SO]: _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517228/4788546)

So, if the *Cygwin* *.dll* exposes some *long* value greater than ***2 ** 64*** (***1 << 64***), it will be truncated in the *Win* process, and in this case a crash might occur. Theoretically, this situation should affect the reverse scenario as well, but it doesn't.

There are other factors that might lead to this behavior, like default memory alignment, and so on.

Comment: Couldn't verify if this was the error in lack of the original setup, but it seems feasible so I accept it as an answer.

Comment: So it has been 4 years, and now I understand your reply much more. Nice work and great debugging test, I don't think I appreciated it nearly enough in it's time. It definitely is the right one.

Comment: @Neinstein: thank you, nice to see that some answers are useful much later on, and people appreciate them.