# pip install error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, pip

I have Python 3.4, running on Windows 10 x64, trying to install `pylint` via pip: `pip install pylint`.

When doing so, I get the following error: `Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279`

However I already have:

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64, Microsoft Visual C++ x86 both Redistributable
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64, Microsoft Visual C++ x86 both Redistributable
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 - 2019 x64, Redistributable
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x64, Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x86 both Redistributable

I saw some other posts with possible solutions that I've tried and did not seem to help to me -

- updating `setuptools` and `virtualenv`
- Downloading the SDK given in the error
- Add `VS110COMNTOOLS, VS120COMNTOOLS, VS140COMNTOOLS` env variables

Of course, after every attempt I've rebooted my PC.

What else could I try to fix this?

Is it possible to install pylint without pip?

Comment: Does this require being run from a Visual Studio 2010 x64 command prompt?  I know for several `c++` buildsystem generators that doing so fixes detection of the compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm What do you mean? I tried running it from PyCharm

Comment: @drescherjm Is it not possible to solve it without using the Visual Studio 2010 x64 command prompt to run the PyCharm?

Answer (score 10):

You don't have any Visual C++, you only have Redistributable packages. They install run-time libraries that are used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ compiler! Install [Visual Studio 2010 Express](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/older-downloads/).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+10.0+is+required%22

Comment: Old versions of Visual Studio are not available anymore in Microsoft's website. So I downloaded the 2019 version, rebooted my PC, and the problem still occurs

Comment: I see Visual Studio 2010 Express at the linked page. Not downloadable?

Comment: I could not find 2010 Express. Downloading now 2017 express, found at the linked page. Could the 2017 solve it or it must be 2010?

Comment: [Which Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to use with a specific Python version ?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F)

Comment: When trying to download .NET framework 4, the installation says that I already have .NET 4 installed. However, when trying to install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET framework 4, I get an error that .NET framework 4 is not found

Comment: @ChikChak Did you try uninstalling your current .NET framework 4 and following the steps again? By steps I mean updating your setuptools again and following the section titled: "Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 standalone: Windows SDK 7.1 (x86, x64, ia64)" of the link phd just sent you?

Comment: @NemPlayer that is the weird part - I cant find the .NET framework under the uninstall programs section in the control panel..

Comment: @ChikChak Try using the .NET framework repair tool: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=246062

Answer (score 4):

#### *Python 3.4*

According to [[Python]: PEP 429 -- Python 3.4 Release Schedule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/#id4) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **Python 3.4 has now reached its end-of-life and has been retired**. No more releases will be made.

The last version (*3.4.10*) was released on *2019/03/18*.

So, you should move away from it (I'd recommend the (current) *LTS* version: *3.**7***). That doesn't magically solve all possible problems, but being a newer version, it requires newer build tools (*VStudio*) which are easier to find, and have a higher probability of installing and running correctly.

**Notes**:

- Even if you manage to solve the problem for this version, you'll be likely to run into it again when trying to install other such packages, as more and more of them will no longer support it
- *Python 3.5+* are built with *VStudio 14.X*. Starting with *VStudio 2015* (*14.0*), *MS* did some changes to improve backward and forward compatibility between *VStudio* versions. More details on [[SO]: How to circumvent Windows Universal CRT headers dependency on vcruntime.h - (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340527/how-to-circumvent-windows-universal-crt-headers-dependency-on-vcruntime-h/50838055#50838055)

#### 2. *Pylint*

[[PyPI]: Pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint) is written **entirely** in *Python* (I checked the source code), so it wouldn't require a *C(++)* compiler. This is also backed up by the existence of the *pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl* file (available for download). 
Some of its dependencies (***wrapt***, ***typed-ast***: which don't have prebuilt binaries for *Python 3.4* on *Win* - makes sense considering the previous bullet) require it.

According to [[PyPA]: pip install - Options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options) (`pip install -h`):

> **--no-deps**

> Don’t install package dependencies.

Now, I don't know your *Pylint* usecase: whether you are using the parts of it that require the above dependencies, but if you don't, simply pass the *--no-deps* argument.

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057581571]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.04.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
> 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.04.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip freeze
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.04.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install --no-deps pylint
> Collecting pylint
>   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/c2/b3f73f4ac008bef6e75bca4992f3963b3f85942e0277237721ef1c151f0d/pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
> Installing collected packages: pylint
> Successfully installed pylint-2.3.1
> You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.04.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip freeze
> pylint==2.3.1
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Pylint dummy usage example - just import it
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.04.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import pylint;print(pylint)"
> <module 'pylint' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py_064_03.04.04_test0\\lib\\site-packages\\pylint\\__init__.py'>
> ```

As seen, the package was **installed**, and it's **usable**.

**Notes**:

- There are (official) prebuilt *Python 3.**5*** (and newer) binaries for *typed-ast*, but not for *wrapt*, so a *Python* upgrade will still require building it (assuming that it's needed)
- You could always turn to unofficial prebuilt binaries. [[UCI.LFD]: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs) is the most comprehensive repository (that I know of), and **contains** the *wrapt* build for *Python 3.4* (but doesn't the *typed-ast* one :) )

#### 3. Or else ...

*Python 3.4* version is built (on *Win*) using *VStudio 2010* (*10.0*). Since it's written in *C*, it requires a *C* compiler. 
More details on **[[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)**.

Every package that contains parts written in *C(++)* (and needs to be built from sources at `pip install` time - meaning that there are no prebuilt binaries on the public repository), also requires the compiler (the compiler version must match the one that *Python* was built with).

The above *URL* lists the 4 items that need to be installed in order to get things going:

- *Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1*
- *Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4*
- The other 2 are dependencies for these 2 (and I tend to think that will be automatically installed)

I didn't (have to) attempt this step, as I already have *VStudio 2010* installed. As a side note, I have 7 *VStudio* versions (with their corresponding *SDK*s) installed, and also I have *30+* *Python* instances (installed, *VEnv*s, custom built by me, installed by other 3<sup>rd</sup>-party software, ...) on my machine.

Once you get the (above) build tools installed (and the *%VS*%* env vars pointing to the desired *VStudio* version - you have to do this manually when having multiple versions), you will be able to install most of the *Python* packages containing *C(++)* code. 
But there will probably be a few exceptions. Here's an example that gave me some headaches: [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 - (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6/54890705#54890705) (check it out - and the *URL*s it references, there's a bunch of useful information there).

I noticed that you're having some problems installing *VStudio 2010*. With the risk of repeating myself, switching to a newer *Python* version would make some of your current problems go away, since it would require newer build tools which are less likely to fail installing. 
Everything else still applies, though.

#### Update *#0*

Concerning the last inquiry in the question:

It's possible to install *Pylint* without *pip*, for example doing (almost) what *pip* does, but manually. However, from what am I concerned, **this would be a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*)**. Anyway, here are the steps:

1. Download and unpack the *.whl* (from section ***#2.***)
2. Copy the (inside) *pylint* *dir*, under *Python*'s *site-packages* *dir*

But again, everything done here is also done **properly** in ***#2.***, so this is truly pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to install pylint from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Visual Studio Code and opening your project from there. From my experience, Visual Studio Code offers to install pylint (and other missing libraries) for you when it recognizes it's missing.