# Command errored out with exit status one

Tags: python, testing

I am installing qark in my pc(Windows 7) for testing purpose. I have installed python 3.7.2 and pip 19.2.3. For next step, I have to install the requirement.txt file while installing, an error occurred(Command errored out with exit status 1:) full error I will give below.

I tried installing it again but error was same I don't know what should I do. Help me.
Thank you

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c
 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\L
ocal\\Temp\\pip-install-6tjj0pbq\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\
HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6tjj0pbq\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(to
kenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"
'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --
egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6tjj0pbq\cffi\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6tjj0pbq\cffi\setup.py",
line 120, in <module>
        if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6tjj0pbq\cffi\setup.py",
line 98, in uses_msvc
        return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')

      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\com
mand\config.py", line 227, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\com
mand\config.py", line 133, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_ms
vccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_ms
vccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1228, in return_env
        self.OSIncludes,
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\msvc.py", line 963, in OSIncludes
        sdkver = self._sdk_subdir
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1057, in _sdk_subdir
        ucrtver = self.si.WindowsSdkLastVersion
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\msvc.py", line 604, in WindowsSdkLastVersion
        self.WindowsSdkDir, 'lib'))
      File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\msvc.py", line 809, in _use_last_dir_name
        for dir_name in reversed(os.listdir(path))
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581571/pip-install-error-microsoft-visual-c-10-0-is-required.

Comment: i have visual studio 2015 and i had installed the same file on ubantu which was successfully downloaded and i didn't have visual studio

Comment: Some env vars are not set correctly. My installation doesn't have a *PlatformSDK* *dir*.

Comment: for env vars i have set for python , pip , git and java is there any thing else i should have

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476784/how-to-install-visual-studio-2015-platformsdk-now?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar problem in which the cmd/PowerShell told me that I was missing a version of Windows Visual C++, so I followed what was written on [THIS](https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/) site, so I didn't have this problem anymore (I also rebooted, for safety):

> 1. Install using any ONE of these choices:
>
>    - Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)
>    - Alternative link to Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).
>    - Offline installer: [vs_buildtools.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe)
> 2. Select: Workloads → C++ build tools.
> 3. Install options: select only the “Windows 10 SDK” (assuming the computer is Windows 10). Optionally, if you want to use MSVC cl.exe C/C++ compiler from the command line, additionally select the C++ build tools, which takes an additional 2 GB disk space.

Moreover, to avoid problems I preferred to install Python **2.7.13** or **3.6** 
because they are the ones with which it has been tested (as indicated by the requirements on the [github page](https://github.com/linkedin/qark)).

After which (again according to the instructions) I installed QARK using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install . --user
```

In the end, to make it work I had to put in the path of the environment variables these definitions:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts         (if you are using Python 2.x.x)
C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts   (if you are using Python 3.x.x)

After that I didn't have any problems running it.
I hope I have been helpful!