# How to fix "cannot find -lvcruntime140.dll" while compiling .py to .pyd?

Tags: python, gcc, cython

#### I am trying to convert my python module from `.py` to `.pyd` dll.

Every time I tried to excute my setup script.

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension("core",  ["core.py"]),
]

setup(
    name = 'core',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

I get this error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvcruntime140.dll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: That's a *VStudio 2015* lib. You should install it and use it to build the *pyd*, if you'r going to use it with *Win* *Python*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340527/how-to-circumvent-windows-universal-crt-headers-dependency-on-vcruntime-h.

Comment: BTW, as it says, that error is from `ld` -- the linker gcc starts after it's finished creating object files -- not gcc itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My problem was solved using these commands:**

- Converting my script to C code via `cython`:

`cython -3 main.py`

- Using gcc directly to convert `.c` to `.pyd` dll:

`gcc main.c -o main.pyd -shared -IC:\Python36\include -LC:\Python36\libs -lpython36`