# Why qt project can throw errors like undefined reference to `__imp_ Py_Initialize' and so on?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I want to add python functions in C++ code.
The project is written using qt.

In Mask.pro I have:

```
...
INCLUDEPATH += "D:/workplace/Python/include"
LIBS += -L"D:/workplace/Python/libs"
...
```

In main.cpp I have:

```
#pragma push_macro("slots")
#undef slots
#include <Python.h>
#pragma pop_macro("slots")
...
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;

Py_Initialize();
pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("Morpho");

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, 0);

Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
Py_DECREF(pModule);
...
```

Errors while compiling:

```
D:\workplace\Python\include\object.h:500: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
debug/main.o: In function `Py_DECREF':
D:/workplace/Python/include/object.h:500: undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:99: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
debug/main.o: In function `Z5qMainiPPc':
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug/../Mask/main.cpp:99: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:100: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:102: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:103: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
```

I just can't find what I am doing wrong or what I even could forget about.

---

Whole .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    QMTIFF.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    processingBlock.cpp

HEADERS += \
    QMTIFF.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    processingBlock.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    Morpho.py

LIBS += -L"D:/workplace/Python/libs" -lpython310

INCLUDEPATH += "D:/workplace/Python/include"
DEPENDPATH += "D:/workplace/Python/include"

LIBS += -L"D:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libtiff/libtiff" -ltiff

INCLUDEPATH += "D:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libtiff/libtiff"
DEPENDPATH += "D:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libtiff/libtiff"
```

All errors and warnings:

```
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\QMTIFF.cpp:103: предупреждение: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
..\Mask\QMTIFF.cpp: In constructor 'QMTIFF::QMTIFF(QString)':
..\Mask\QMTIFF.cpp:103:16: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     } while (n < NOfPages);
          ~~^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\QMTIFF.cpp:53: предупреждение: unused parameter 'test' [-Wunused-parameter]
..\Mask\QMTIFF.cpp:53:24: warning: unused parameter 'test' [-Wunused-parameter]
 QMTIFF::QMTIFF(QString test)
                        ^~~~
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\main.cpp:17: предупреждение: unused variable 'Num' [-Wunused-variable]
..\Mask\main.cpp: In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':
..\Mask\main.cpp:17:18: warning: unused variable 'Num' [-Wunused-variable]
     unsigned int Num = 1190;
                  ^~~
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\main.cpp:25: предупреждение: unused variable 'from' [-Wunused-variable]
..\Mask\main.cpp:25:9: warning: unused variable 'from' [-Wunused-variable]
     int from = 1001;
         ^~~~
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\main.cpp:26: предупреждение: unused variable 'to' [-Wunused-variable]
..\Mask\main.cpp:26:9: warning: unused variable 'to' [-Wunused-variable]
     int to  =  1190;
         ^~
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\main.cpp:96: предупреждение: unused variable 'pArgs' [-Wunused-variable]
..\Mask\main.cpp:96:15: warning: unused variable 'pArgs' [-Wunused-variable]
     PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
               ^~~~~
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\Mask\main.cpp:96: предупреждение: unused variable 'pValue' [-Wunused-variable]
..\Mask\main.cpp:96:23: warning: unused variable 'pValue' [-Wunused-variable]
     PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
                       ^~~~~~
D:\workplace\Python\include\object.h:500: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
debug/main.o: In function `Py_DECREF':
D:/workplace/Python/include/object.h:500: undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:98: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
debug/main.o: In function `Z5qMainiPPc':
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug/../Mask/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:99: error: undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:101: error: undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
C:\Projects\Cproject\QT\Mask\build-Mask-Desktop-Debug\..\Mask\main.cpp:102: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: As I understsnd, I jast need to install libpyton, but where I can find it for windows?

Comment: Hmm, what build toolchain did you configure in *Creator*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Python* (at least the official binaries) for *Win* is built using *VStudio* ([[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)). 
According to an output line added after a while (`:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`), it seems a different build toolchain (looks like a port from *Nix* (*MinGW*, *MSYS2*, *Cygwin*, ...)) is used.

It's generally advisable not to mix build toolchains, as that could yield errors (at build time, or (even worse) crashes at runtime). Check [[SO]: How to circumvent Windows Universal CRT headers dependency on vcruntime.h (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838055/4788546) for a remotely related example.

Try setting *VStudio* (might need to install it - *Community Edition* is free) in your *.pro* file, like in the image below (don't mind the older version, this is what I have configured already):

[image: Img00]

---

This (original answer) is a generic advice and is not the cause for the current failure, as the library is automatically included (via *pyconfig.h*).

You specified where the linker should search for libraries, but you didn't specify which libraries to use. Check [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546) for more details on building on *Win*.

Inside *Python*'s *lib* directory (*"D:/workplace/Python/libs"* in your case), there should be a file called ***python${PYTHON_MAJOR}${PYTHON_MINOR}.lib*** depending on which *Python* version you are using (*e.g.* ***python39.lib*** for *Python 3.9*). You need to let the linker know about it:

```cpp
LIBS += -L"D:/workplace/Python/libs" -lpython39
```

**Note**: On *Win* you don't have to separately install *Python* packages (*python**, *libpython**, *libpython*-dev*, ...) as they are all contained by the (official) installer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, but even after redacting .pro file I have the same problem

In Mask.pro I have:
...
LIBS += -L"D:/workplace/Python/libs" -lpython310

INCLUDEPATH += "D:/workplace/Python/include"
DEPENDPATH += "D:/workplace/Python/include"
...

Comment: How do you build it? From Creator?

Comment: Yes, I build it from Qt Creator

Comment: What other reasons for these errors could be?

Addition:
Another library has also been included in the .pro file as follows:
...
LIBS += -L"D:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libtiff/libtiff" -ltiff

INCLUDEPATH += "D:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libtiff/libtiff"
DEPENDPATH += "D:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libtiff/libtiff"
...

This lib works correctly.

Comment: Wait a minute.... What I stated in my answer is a generic solution, but for *Python* it isn't necessary, as the lib is included in one of the header filers. How did you install *D:/workplace/Python*? Is there any *D:/workplace/Python/libs/python310.lib*?

Comment: Python, as far as I remember, was installed from python.org

There are next files in libs:
 _tkinter.lib
python3.lib
python310.lib

Comment: Please post the whole *.pro* file. Don't you also have in the *Compile Output* tab (in the lower window part) something like: *warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'*?

Comment: And in the D:/workplace/Python/include we have lots of .h files

Comment: After all errors compiler throws this: 
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 

Whole .pro file is in the new answer.

Comment: Don't add extra data in answers, edit the question instead. Also please add the full build log including the compile and link commands outputs errors. and warnings

Comment: I understand that it is not correct to do this, but, unfortunately, when creating a question, it is not allowed to fill it with so much code and so few comments.

Comment: All errors and warnings are added to the comment