# How to call v8 functions directly from pdfium.dll

Tags: c++, dll, v8, lib, pdfium

I'm trying to include pdfium in my development as dll. Most of FPDF_* functions are directly accessible, however I cannot reference v8 related functions, e.g. `v8::initializeICU()`, `v8::InitializePlatform()`. Since I'm totally new to this project, and have to raise following questions:

1. Are v8 related functions really unavailable in pdfium.dll?
2. If not, which lib files I should reference in a c++ project, in order to call the v8 related functions?
3. Is there any way to reference v8 functions without referring to the lib files?

Comment: How are you trying to call those funcs? Does the *.dll* come with one (or more) *.h* file(s)? You are making a confusion between *.dll* and *.lib* files. You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116437/errors-when-linking-to-protobuf-3-on-msvc-2013/35118400#35118400 for some details. Yes it is possible to call functions without using lib files, using `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

PDFium does not include v8 library code. You'll need to link the v8 libraries as well as the PDFium libraries. You'll probably need the libv8_libbase and libv8_libplatform libraries.