# LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug'

Tags: visual-c++, dll, lib

This error is generated during linking. How to resolve this issue? Can anyone help here?

How to figure out the issue and what could be the resolution?

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > "Runtime Library" setting.  All code you link must be compiled with the same setting.  Including static library projects, the usual troublemaker.  Or in other words, you can't link the release build of a library with the debug build of your program.  Did you google this error message?  First hit is good.

Comment: I have complied the .lib(say xyz.lib) with Runtime Library as  Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd). "xyz.lib" has been created successfully. Now, when I am trying to generate an executable(say abc.exe)  using this lib file(xyz.lib). it is throwing above linking error.['MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug']

Comment: Can anyone give some pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: [\[SO\]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546)